# Обратный порядок кнопок на эмуляторе

Tags: android, xml, kotlin, эмулятор

Всем привет!
Проблема заключается в следующем. Создал несколько кнопок (xml) для графического отображения. Вот код одной кнопки:

```
<Button
        android:id="@+id/toast_button"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginEnd="24dp"
        android:background="@color/screenButton"
        android:fontFamily="@font/montserrat"
        android:text="Toast"
        android:textAllCaps="false"
        app:backgroundTint="@color/screenButton"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textView"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.5" />
```

Вот на первой картинке виден верный порядок.

[image: Прямой порядок]

Но при запуске на эмуляторе порядок становится обратным.
Возможно, это какая-то базовая ошибка, из-за отсутствия опыта не могу до неё докопаться.

[image: Обратный порядок на эмуляторе]

Comment: Посмотрите на первую картинку: на ней в `ActionBar` текст находится справа (обычно он слева), на второй же картинке текст на месте. Возможно, вы упустили где-либо `android:layoutDirection="ltr"` (или "rtl")

Comment: Спасибо! Добавил android:layoutDirection="rtl" и всё встало на свои места!